# Hard-Drives are not detected by Ubuntu LiveCd or Installation

Tags: installation, disk, gparted

I'm reposting my question 'cause it seems the previous is alreadt forgotten.

I can boot to windows 7 normally.

However in Ubuntu - I cannot boot. When using a Ubuntu Live CD, I cannot see my drives in gparted or disk utility.

Launching Nautilus - no drives are seen

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a problem with your fstab, or your partition table. You said you can boot into windows, can Ubuntu not see Windows? If so that is most likely a problem with your fstab file.

If gparted can't see any partitions that is most likely a problem with your partition table as I think gparted bypasses fstab and all that.

Try downloading testdisk from the repos in your live CD and do a scan and see if that is able to see your partitions.